# Node 1 is not mining the transaction of node 2

Tags: go-ethereum

I have created and started two nodes

### Node 1:

```
$./geth --datadir p22333/ --port 22333 account new

$./geth --datadir p22333/ --port 22333 init genesis.json

$./geth --datadir p22333/ --port 22333 console
```

### Node 2:

```
$./geth --datadir p22334/ --port 22334 account new

$./geth --datadir p22334/ --port 22334 init genesis.json

$./geth --datadir p22334/ --port 22334 console
```

Later I added the node 1 with node 2 using the `admin.addpeer()`

On Node 1 console:

```
admin.addpeer("hexaddress of node 2")
net.peerCount
```

> 1

On node 2 console:

```
net.peerCount
```

> 1

```
personal.unlockAccount("hexaddress of node 2", "password")
```

> true

```
eth.sendTransactions({from:"hexaddress of node 2",to:"hexaddress of node 1",value:web3:toWei(40,"ether"),gas:30000})
```

> 0x2312312......

```
eth.pendingTransaction
```

> {
>   hash:21...
>   from:31....
>   }

On node 1:

```
eth.pendingTransaction
```

> []

It is not showing the pending transactions on other nodes as well as When I mine on node 1, it is not taking the transaction of node 2. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

1-  use the same network id :`--networkid`

2- consult the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network) to see how to use admin.addpeer()

```
admin.addPeer("enode://f4642fa65af50cfdea8fa7414a5def7bb7991478b768e296f5e4a54e8b995de102e0ceae2e826f293c481b5325f89be6d207b003382e18a8ecba66fbaf6416c0@IP_address:30303")
```

node URL is get by using `admin.nodeInfo`

3- `personal.unlockAccount` is used for etherum address not node address

4- more details on nodes connections : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network

Comment: even after --networkid, same problem exist. I used --networkid 121

Comment: now the problem is solved. I was not synchronizing. thanks